# Twitter bootstrap tabs location.hash change issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to load specific twitter bootstrap tab on window.load

```
$(function () {

    if (location.hash !== '') {
        $('#myTab a[href="' + location.hash + '"]').tab('show');
    } else {
        $('#myTab a:first').tab('show');
    }

    $('#myTab a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function(e) {
          location.hash = $(e.target).attr('href').substr(1);
          return false ;
    });
})
```

this code works fine . my issue is there a **jump** to specific tab div content, how could i disable **browser's default location hash change event** for twitter bootstrap tab . What changes should I make to above code ?

Comment: can we see some working fiddle so that we can check what is the exact problem ??

Comment: @Sachin .. I got solution!. added a prefix so the hash, that doesn't reference any DOM element on that page `$('#myTab a[href="' + location.hash.replace('tab_','') + '"]').tab('show')` ! thanks

Comment: @rab please add this as an answer to your question (and accept it later on) so that everybody here knows your problem was solved.

Comment: @marijin added solution

Comment: Great! If I recall correctly you have to wait some time (maybe a day or two) before you can mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@marijn commented , I have added a prefix to the hash, that doesn't reference any DOM element on that page

```
if (location.hash !== '') {
    $('#myTab a[href="' + location.hash.replace('tab_','') + '"]').tab('show');
} else {
    $('#myTab a:first').tab('show');
}

$('#myTab a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function(e) {
      location.hash = 'tab_'+  e.target.hash.substr(1) ; 
      return false ;
});
```